# PHP-Data txt - Two-dimensional Array - Data grouping per record

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I need to read, line aligns and group by `(Cd)`, which is the only index of each record. Thus, `(Cd)` refers to each new record, which may contain several sub groups: `(11)`, `(22)`, `(Co)`, etc. These sub groups may contain an additional line (see example of `(Co)` in the first record, which should concatenate the lines containing "for cabinet" and "for closet.").

My TXT file structure, is this:[inventory.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6OnlWzzBEwARzROR3R4WkhkLTQ)

```
>No. 0012 of 01/31/2016
>No. 0012 of 01/31/2016
>(Cd) 12345
>(11) Cod1-023 
>(22) 22/12/1945 
>(Co) locking doors 
>For cabinet 
>For closet. 
>(Cd) 23456 
>(11) Cod1-055 
>(21) 01/01/2005 
>(22) drawer iron 
>,wood 
>,aluminum 
>(Cd) 78920 
>(22) Cod1-077 
>(54) 2/22/1975 
>(Co) clip Aluminum or iron 
>(74) anodized 
>(Cd) 0002525 
>(Di) Cod4-07100 
>(11) 02/22/2017 
>(22) shirt Red green 
>(54) yellow buttons 
>(Co) mango 
>,avocado 
>,cherry
```

I implemented the following routine but, after much research and modifications, I was not able to group the sub indices:

Together, I need a routine to transfer the data from the array to variables and, later, to the mysql DB.

If anyone can give me a light, thank you.

```
$cd = [];
$group = [];
$counter = 0;

$file = fopen ('inventory.txt', 'r');
while (! feof ($file)) {
    $row = trim (fgets ($file, 1024));
    // $row = trim ($row);
    if (substr ($row, 0, 4) == '(cd)') {
        $counter = 0;
        if (! empty ($group)) {
            $cd [$id] = $group;
            $group = [];
            $counter = 0;
        }
        $id = substr ($row, 5, strlen ($row) -5);
        $cd [$id] [] = $line;
    } else {
        if (substr ($row, 0, 4)! == '(11)') {
            if (isset ($group [$counter-1])) {
                $group [$counter -1]. = ''. $line;
                $counter--;
            }
        } else {
            $group [] = $row;
        }
        $counter ++;
    }
}

$cd [$id] = $group;

fclose ($file);

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($cd);
exit;

// -------------------------
// routine to transfer data from array to variables
$keys = array_keys ($cd);
for ($i = 0; $i <count ($cd); $i ++) {
    echo $keys [$i]. "<br>";
    foreach ($cd [$keys [$i]] as $key => $value) {
        echo $key. ":". $value. "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for editing your question to attach the file content rows.  Here is my new solution.

This will disallow concatenation for any lines immediately after a `(22)` line.
If there are other triggers beyond `(22)` that should indicate concatenation is unwanted, modify the `$concat` condition in the second `elseif` block.

```
$cd=[];  // declare array
$i=-1;  // set outer index
$concat=true;
$file=fopen('inventory.txt','r');
while(!feof($file)){
    $row=trim(fgets($file,1024));
    if(preg_match('/^\(Cd\)\s(.+)/',$row,$match)){  // capture Cd numbers
        ++$i;  // increment outer_index
        $j=-1;  // reset inner_index
        $id=$match[1];  // store cd value
        $concat=true;
    }elseif(preg_match('/^(\(..\)\s.*)/',$row,$match)){  // capture Cd data
        ++$j;  // this is a new innerarray element, increment its index
        $cd[$i][$id][$j]=$match[1];  // push element into array
        $concat=(strpos($match[1],'(22)')!==0?true:false);
    }elseif(isset($id) && $concat){  // ignore all file header content
        $cd[$i][$id][$j].=" $row";  // concatenate to last element
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_export($cd);  // display in true nested form
echo "</pre>";

foreach($cd as $outer_index=>$cdarrays){
    foreach($cdarrays as $id=>$innerarrays){
        foreach($innerarrays as $inner_index=>$line){
            echo "$outer_index : $id : $inner_index = $line<br>";  // display keys & values by row
        }
    }
}
```

The $cd array will have this structure:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    12345 => 
    array (
      0 => '(11) Cod1-023',
      1 => '(22) 22/12/1945',
      2 => '(Co) locking doors For cabinet For closet. ',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    23456 => 
    array (
      0 => '(11) Cod1-055',
      1 => '(21) 01/01/2005',
      2 => '(22) drawer iron',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    78920 => 
    array (
      0 => '(22) Cod1-077',
      1 => '(54) 2/22/1975',
      2 => '(Co) clip Aluminum or iron',
      3 => '(74) anodized',
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    '0002525' => 
    array (
      0 => '(Di) Cod4-07100',
      1 => '(11) 02/22/2017',
      2 => '(22) shirt Red green',
      3 => '(54) yellow buttons',
      4 => '(Co) mango ,avocado ,cherry',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Or if you want to view it in a flattened/verbose style:

```
0 : 12345 : 0 = (11) Cod1-023
0 : 12345 : 1 = (22) 22/12/1945
0 : 12345 : 2 = (Co) locking doors For cabinet For closet. 
1 : 23456 : 0 = (11) Cod1-055
1 : 23456 : 1 = (21) 01/01/2005
1 : 23456 : 2 = (22) drawer iron
2 : 78920 : 0 = (22) Cod1-077
2 : 78920 : 1 = (54) 2/22/1975
2 : 78920 : 2 = (Co) clip Aluminum or iron
2 : 78920 : 3 = (74) anodized
3 : 0002525 : 0 = (Di) Cod4-07100
3 : 0002525 : 1 = (11) 02/22/2017
3 : 0002525 : 2 = (22) shirt Red green
3 : 0002525 : 3 = (54) yellow buttons
3 : 0002525 : 4 = (Co) mango ,avocado ,cherry
```

Comment: mickmackusa,
The moderator changed the original layout of my text file, which impaired the interpretation. Here is the file layout I get from the client:

No. 0012 of 01/31/2016

No. 0012 of 01/31/2016

(Cd) 12345
(11) Cod1-023
(22) 22/12/1945
(Co) locking doors
For cabinet
For closet.

(Cd) 23456
...

I have to read line by line. Its algorithm looks great but does not concatenate the additional lines of the subgroups. (See example in the first record, which should concatenate the lines containing "for cabinet" and "for closet.").

Comment: Mickmackusa, his algorithm is grouping hair (Cd) and can have two CDs with equal values but with different sub groups. Another problem is that preg_match is taking values between parentheses not between values, when it should just pick up those in the beginning. Example: substr ($row, 0, 5) === '(Cd)'

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso Welcome to SO. If you want to alert another user to a comment directed to them, prefix your comment with `@[username]`.  Without the @ symbol, the alert will not be issued to them.

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso if my updated answer sufficiently solves your problem please award me the green tick, otherwise please explain what remains unsolved.

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso  Do you want the parenthetical prefixes removed from the Cd's subarrays like I have done with `(Cd) `?  e.g. Remove `(Di) `, `(11) `, etc ?

Comment: //I discovered why not pick up values containing punctuation. Is it correct preg_match?
I need to return any value, containing any character, punctuation, existing in the value of Cd
So find '(Cd) 082','(Cd) 0.2','(Cd) 8,2','(Cd) PR','(Cd) PR-nulidades'
    if(preg_match('/^\(Cd\)\s([\sA-Za-z0-9.,-]*)/',$row,$match)){  // capture Cd numbers

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso I have edited my regex pattern for the `Cd` lines.  Now it will capture any characters after `(Cd) ` instead of only numbers.  I made the assumption the Cd's were always integers because that was true in your sample file's text.  If  my code still isn't working for you, please explain where/why it is failing and I'll help.

Comment: I have much to thank him for his enormous contribution..So far the code has been excellent. But there are lines that should not be concatenated, such as line (22) that should not be concatenated with the following ones, containing ', wood, aluminum'. How can I do this? These additional lines need to be captured for any one variable, which will have the value carried to the DB.

Comment: I did not realize that you had edited the post and so I deleted the new questions. I apologize for the bad English environment. I'm learning to use the Forum. Excellent algorithm. But if the value of (Cd) is alphanumerical or letters only, it gives error. Example: (Cd) xj21 If the value of (Cd) has a punctuation, it excludes part of the value Example: (Cd) 32.5

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso I've just retested my latest edit, and I can't get it to break on alphanumeric or alphabetical or Cd's that have symbols.  Please offer a specific Cd value where it fails for you, then I will be able to recreate it for myself and offer a solution.  Using English as a second language is not something to apologize for.  I have ESL friends and I am very patient because my French, as a Second Language, is horrendous!

Comment: Excuse me. I exclude the answer that was as a question, as you suggested and it was the end.I have much to thank him for his enormous contribution..So far the code has been excellent. But there are lines that should not be concatenated, such as line (22) that should not be concatenated with the following ones, containing ', wood, aluminum'. How can I do this? These additional lines need to be captured for any one variable, which will have the value carried to the DB.

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso  Can you explain why `, wood, aluminum` should not be included?  Should `For cabinet For closet.` and `,avocado ,cherry` also be removed?  If lines not starting with `(` must be removed, that's easy.  If `, wood, aluminum` should be handled differently to `For cabinet For closet.` and `,avocado ,cherry` then you will have to explain to me how the program should decide which to keep and which to omit.

Comment: As an example, whenever you are in the index line (22), you should not concatenate the following lines.cabinet and for closet. Belong to the index (Co) and, avocado, cherry to the other (Co).did you get it?

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso  I have added a custom concatenation condition so that un-prefixed lines after a `(22)` line will be omitted.  Did I earn the green tick and an upvote yet?

Comment: I really have to apologize because I do not know how to use the Forum properly and only now I have searched for some information in Help. I thought the green tick and an up vote yet were just in the conclusion. As for the code, this is what you need to do, but the lines that you did not concatenate have been deleted and I need them. When in line 22, the following lines, containing ", wood, aluminum" must be concatenated in a variable to be created, for example: $ 22_trash, because the value will be sent to the DB.
2 => '(22) drawer iron',3 => '(22_trash) ,wood ,aluminum',

Comment: @JohnnyCardoso I thought we were concluded.  This question seems to extend and extend.  I am still happy to help.  To handle the omitted lines, create a fourth condition statement that says: `elseif(isset($id) && !$concat){ // assign your trash variable/data here  }`

Comment: $cd[$i][$id][$j].=" $row";  // concatenate to last element      $trash.=" $row"; ?  But how do I transfer pro foreach, without adding to the other records?

Answer (score 0):

@mickmackusa I have much to thank for your patience and contribution. His code was excellent, but he was eliminating the lines he was leaping (22). So, I modified the structure to capture the values of those following, including in a new ID inside the array.
My array knowledge is very limited, but the code is functional for my needs.
In case you can contribute to simplify the operation that I built, I'm happy to know.

Why error Occurs "Warning: Undefined offset: 3 and Undefined offset: 5, in this line: $cd[$i][$id][$j]. = "$Row";

```
$cd=[];  // declare array
$trash=[];
$i=-1;  // set outer index
$concat=true;
$file=fopen('inventory.txt','r');
while(!feof($file)){
    $row=trim(fgets($file,1024));

    if(preg_match('/^\(Cd\)\s(.+)/',$row,$match)){  // capture Cd numbers
        ++$i;  // increment outer_index
        $j=-1;  // reset inner_index
        $id=$match[1];  // store cd value
        $concat=true;
        $row_previous=false;
        $row_ob=false;
    }elseif(preg_match('/^(\(..\)\s.*)/',$row,$match)){  // capture Cd data
        ++$j;  // this is a new innerarray element, increment its index
        $cd[$i][$id][$j]=$match[1];  // push element into array
        //$concat=(strpos($match[1],'(Co)')!==0?true:false);
        If (substr($row, 0, 5) == '(Co) ') {   
            $row_previous=true;
        }

    }elseif(isset($id)){  // ignore all file header content
            If (($row_previous == true)and ($row_ob !== true)){   
            ++$j; //increment its index to insert variable value created for the additional lines
            $row="(Ob) ". (trim($row)); //create pre value variable
            $row_ob=true;
            $cd[$i][$id][$j].="$row ";  // concatenate to last element to new
        }else{
        $cd[$i][$id][$j].=" $row";  // concatenate to last element
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_export($cd);  // display in true nested form
echo "</pre>";


foreach($cd as $outer_index=>$cdarrays){
    foreach($cdarrays as $id=>$innerarrays){
        foreach($innerarrays as $inner_index=>$line){
            echo "$outer_index : $id : $inner_index = $line<br>";  // display keys & values by row
        }
    }
}
```